# Saving a file to Application Data in c#

Tags: c#, windows-vista

I used the following method to save a file to the folder  Application Data in c#

```
string path = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Its working fine in windows XP, but i cannt find such a folder path i Windows vista.
Where is this folder located in Vista and how can i save the file to this folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work out the folder for you in the background. Do you mean you don't know exactly where the file has been saved to?

In Vista if you go to Run and type %APPDATA% that should bring up the Application Data folder and your file should be in there.

The path is essentially

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming
```

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me here, on Vista:

```
PS> [environment]::GetFolderPath([environment+specialfolder]::ApplicationData)
C:\...\AppData\Roaming
```

The exact details on *where* that folder is shouldn't concern you anyway. After all, you want a *special folder* which has certain semantics and you will get it. Regardless of where exactly it is.